# How to get the list of constant terms of linear equations?

Tags: equation-solving, linear-algebra

A system of linear equations:

$\left\{\begin{aligned} x_{1}+3 x_{2}+x_{3} &=2 \\ 3 x_{1}+4 x_{2}+2 x_{3} &=9 \\-x_{1}-5 x_{2}+4 x_{3} &=10 \\ 2 x_{1}+7 x_{2}+x_{3} &=1 \end{aligned}\right.$

I know how to get its coefficient matrix.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
eqns = {\!\(TraditionalForm\`
\*SubscriptBox[\(x\), \(1\)] + 3 
\*SubscriptBox[\(x\), \(2\)] + 
\*SubscriptBox[\(x\), \(3\)]\[AlignmentMarker] == 
      2\), \!\(TraditionalForm\`3 
\*SubscriptBox[\(x\), \(1\)] + 4 
\*SubscriptBox[\(x\), \(2\)] + 2 
\*SubscriptBox[\(x\), \(3\)]\[AlignmentMarker] == 
      9\), \!\(TraditionalForm\`\(\[Minus]
\*SubscriptBox[\(x\), \(1\)]\) \[Minus] 5 
\*SubscriptBox[\(x\), \(2\)] + 4 
\*SubscriptBox[\(x\), \(3\)]\[AlignmentMarker] == 
      10\), \!\(TraditionalForm\`2 
\*SubscriptBox[\(x\), \(1\)] + 7 
\*SubscriptBox[\(x\), \(2\)] + 
\*SubscriptBox[\(x\), \(3\)]\[AlignmentMarker] == 1\)};
c = CoefficientArrays[eqns, Variables@eqns];
mc = MatrixForm@c[[2]]
```

> $\left(\begin{array}{ccc}1 & 3 & 1 \\ 3 & 4 & 2 \\ -1 & -5 & 4 \\ 2 & 7 & 1\end{array}\right)$

How to get the list of constant terms of these linear equations, i.e `{2,9,10,1}`?

Comment: `eqns[[All, -1]]`?

Comment: @bmf, I get  `{2, 9, 10, 1}` both in version 11.3 (Windows 64b) and in version 13.0.0 (Wolfram Cloud)

Comment: @kglr Thank you! It's work. Another question, what if the constant term is not written on the same side of the equal sign? For example, constant terms are mixed with variable terms. Is there a more general method?

Comment: @kglr I know. there were some other lines that caused some confusion, and hence I deleted. sorry about that

Comment: I'm confused. You already know `CoefficientArrays`, why are you still having difficulty in obtaining the list of constant terms? Or you just obtain this code sample from somewhere without understanding it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
Part[-Normal[CoefficientArrays[eqns]], 1]
(*{2, 9, 10, 1}*)
```

The system coefficients:

```
Part[Normal[CoefficientArrays[eqns]], 2]
(*{{1, 3, 1}, {3, 4, 2}, {-1, -5, 4}, {2, 7, 1}}*)
```

Comment: (+1) nice approach!!!

Comment: I found this approach useful for some uses of LinearSolve. Greetings, bmf!

Comment: Nice approach! Thank you!