How to obtain the characteristic equation of first-order PDE in the method of characteristics?
The following first-order partial differential equations:
(1) $x \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + y \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} + xy \frac{\partial u}{\partial z} = 0$;
eqn1 = x D[u[x, y, z], {x, 1}] + y D[u[x, y, z], {y, 1}] + 
    x y D[u[x, y, z], {z, 1}] == 0;

(2) $y \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} - x \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = x - y$;
eqn2 = y D[u[x, y], x] - x D[u[x, y], y] == x - y;

(3) $y \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} + z \frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = \frac{y}{x}$;
eqn3 = y D[z[x, y], x] + z[x, y] D[z[x, y], y] == y/x;

(4) $x \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = x + y + 2z$.
eqn4 = x D[z[x, y], x] == x + y + 2 z[x, y];

Their characteristic equations (the Method of Characteristics) are:
(1)
$
\frac{dx}{x} = \frac{dy}{y} = \frac{dz}{xy}.
 $
(2)
$
\frac{dx}{y} = \frac{dy}{-x} = \frac{du}{x - y}.
 $
(3)
$
\frac{dx}{y} = \frac{dy}{z} = \frac{x dz}{y}.
 $
(4)
$
\frac{dx}{x} = \frac{dy}{0} = \frac{dz}{x + y + 2z}.
 $
For a general first-order linear partial differential equation system:
$
A_1(x, y, z) \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + A_2(x, y, z) \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} + A_3(x, y, z) \frac{\partial u}{\partial z} = 0,
$
where $A_1, A_2, A_3$ are known functions, the characteristic equations are obtained through the following steps:
For each independent variable (such as x, y and z), we construct a system of ordinary differential equations (ODEs):
$
\frac{dx}{A_1} = \frac{dy}{A_2} = \frac{dz}{A_3}.
$
How can I write code in MMA that can automatically output the characteristic equation?
Thank you in advance!
EDIT-20241124
The following two pieces of code respectively address cases involving four and three variables. They can solve most situations but still lack generality.
1.
ClearAll["Global`*"];


ExtractCharacteristicEquations[eqn_, uExpr_, vars_List] := 
 Module[{lhs, rhs, expr, a, b, c, d, eqns, 
   uSymbol},{lhs, 
    rhs} = {eqn[[1]], eqn[[2]]};
  expr = Expand[lhs - rhs];
 
  a = Coefficient[expr, D[uExpr, vars[[1]]]];
  b = Coefficient[expr, D[uExpr, vars[[2]]]];
  c = Coefficient[expr, D[uExpr, vars[[3]]]];

  d = Coefficient[expr, uExpr];

  If[d =!= 0,
   eqns = {Inactive[Divide][Dt[vars[[1]]], a], 
     Inactive[Divide][Dt[vars[[2]]], b], 
     Inactive[Divide][Dt[vars[[3]]], c], 
     Inactive[Divide][Dt[vars[[3]]], (-d)]},
   eqns = {Inactive[Divide][Dt[vars[[1]]], a], 
     Inactive[Divide][Dt[vars[[2]]], b], 
     Inactive[Divide][Dt[vars[[3]]], c]}];
Equal @@ eqns]


vars = {x, y, z, u};

(*Example 1:Without zero-order terms*)

eqn1 = x D[u[x, y, z], x] + y D[u[x, y, z], y] + 
    x y D[u[x, y, z], z] == 0;

newEqn1 = ExtractCharacteristicEquations[eqn1, u[x, y, z], vars]
(*Output:Dt[x]/x==Dt[y]/y==Dt[z]/(x y)*)

(*Example 2:With zero-order terms*)
eqn2 = 2 D[u[x, y, z], x] - 3 D[u[x, y, z], y] + D[u[x, y, z], z] + 
    4 u[x, y, z] == 0;

newEqn2 = ExtractCharacteristicEquations[eqn2, u[x, y, z], vars]
(*Output:Dt[x]/2==Dt[y]/(-3)==Dt[z]/1==Dt[u]/(-4)*)




ClearAll["Global`*"];


ExtractCharacteristicEquations[eqn_, derivs_List, vars_List] := 
 Module[{lhs, rhs, expr, A, B, C, newEqn},{lhs, rhs} = {eqn[[1]], eqn[[2]]};
  expr = Expand[lhs - rhs];
  
  A = Coefficient[expr, derivs[[1]]];
  B = Coefficient[expr, derivs[[2]]];
  
  C = Simplify[-(expr - A derivs[[1]] - B derivs[[2]])];
  
  newEqn = 
   Equal @@ {Inactive[Divide][Dt[vars[[1]]], A], 
     Inactive[Divide][Dt[vars[[2]]], B], 
     Inactive[Divide][Dt[vars[[3]]], C]};
  newEqn]


derivs = {D[z[x, y], x], D[z[x, y], y]};
vars = {x, y, z};


eqn1 = x D[z[x, y], x] == x + y + 2 z[x, y];


newEqn1 = ExtractCharacteristicEquations[eqn1, derivs, vars]



How will you use GetDerivatives? 2. What's the purpose of the pattern FreeQ[#, D[_, {_, _}], {1}] in GetDerivatives? 3. Once again, please put a bit more effort in understanding the code you've obtained: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/265580/1871


The method for solving characteristic equations, as explained in the question, is not complicated. The key lies in extracting the coefficients of the derivatives and then constructing a chain equation.


OK, let me be straightforward: if you're just generating code with tools like ChatGPT without understanding it, then such "effort" is worse than "no effort". 5. Please show us the Mathematica code for these equation systems so we can play with them easier.


…Why do you refuse to learn the usage of CoefficientArrays? Which part are you having difficulty?

Please specify the boundary conditions for each one of the four cases. Without boundary condition any PDE has infinity many solutions. If a numerical calculus gives a solution without boundary condition this so-called solution is an uncertain solution.

Some arguably irrelevant talking first. Though I claimed that "I won't vote to close or downvote as long as the questions are on-topic" here, thanks to user:68574, I've thought more about this topic in past 2 years, and my conclusion has slightly changed: if a question is on-topic, I won't vote to close of course, but if I think the asker hasn't shown enough effort, I downvote. Given that:

You're a member for 4 years asking 88 undeleted questions.

A strongly related function CoefficientArrays has already appeared in the body of this question of yours but you seem to refuse to learn its usage.


I don't think you've shown enough effort, so (-1).
Then let me solve the problem. The key idea is not complicated. Given that:

CoefficientArrays can extract the coefficients of any 1st order PDE.

Cases can extract the dependent and independent variables with a simple Derivative[__][h_][var__] pattern.


The problem can be solved in following fashion:
(* eqn1 is the same as yours so omitted here. *)

{head, vars} = 
 First@Cases[eqn1, Derivative[__][h_][var__] :> {h, {var}}, Infinity, 1]

(* {u, {x, y, z}} *)

rhs = {-1, 1} CoefficientArrays[eqn1, 
    Grad[head @@ vars, vars]] // Flatten

(* {0, x, y, x y} *)

lhs = Flatten@{head, vars}' // Thread

(* {u', x', y', z'} *)

Then lhs == rhs is the desired solution with valid syntax, which is supported by DSolve since version 14.1:
DSolve[lhs == rhs]


If one is in older version, then the standard syntax is needed. We just need a bit more expression manipulation:
newlhs = Through@lhs[t]
(* {u'[t], x'[t], y'[t], z'[t]} *)

newvars = Flatten@{head, vars};
addt = h : Alternatives @@ newvars :> h[t];
newrhs = rhs /. addt
(* {0, x[t], y[t], x[t] y[t]} *)

DSolve[newlhs == newrhs, newvars, t]

If one insists, the equations can be formed as Lagrange–Charpit equations of course:
eqnonstandard = Dt@newvars/(rhs /. 0 -> HoldForm[0]) // Apply@Equal // Append@Dt@t


The code has been transformed to TraditionalForm with Ctrl+Shift+t for better illustration. I've kept the $du$ term and added the $dt$ term for preciseness and convenience. This equation can also be used in DSolve with a minimal transform:
DSolve[eqnonstandard /. addt, newvars /. addt, t] // ReleaseHold

With some more effort, a general function can be created:
ClearAll[characteristicEquations];

Options[characteristicEquations] = {"form" -> "abstract", 
  "dummyVariable" -> \[FormalT]}; 
characteristicEquations[eq_, opt : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 characteristicEquations[eq, ##, opt] & @@ 
  First@Cases[eq, Derivative[__][h_][var__] :> {h, {var}}, Infinity, 
    1];

characteristicEquations[eq_, h_, var_, opt : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 With[{newvar = Flatten@{h, var}, hvar = h @@ var, 
   t = OptionValue["dummyVariable"]}, 
  With[{lhs = Thread[newvar'], 
    rhs = Flatten[{-1, 1} CoefficientArrays[eq, D[hvar, {var}]]] /. 
      hvar :> h}, Thread@Switch[OptionValue["form"],
     "abstract", lhs == rhs,
     "standard", 
     Through@lhs[t] == (rhs /. Thread[newvar -> Through@newvar[t]]),
     "Charpit", 
     Equal @@ (Dt[newvar]/(rhs /. 0 -> HoldForm[0])) // Append@Dt@t]]]

Usage:
eqn1 // characteristicEquations
(* {u' == 0, x' == x, y' == y, z' == x y} *)

characteristicEquations[eqn2, "form" -> "standard"]


characteristicEquations[eqn3, "form" -> "Charpit"]


characteristicEquations[eqn4, "dummyVariable" -> τ, 
 "form" -> "standard"]
(*
{z'[τ] == x[τ] + y[τ] + 2 z[τ], 
 x'[τ] == x[τ], 
 y'[τ] == 0}
 *)

eqs = {eqn1, eqn2, eqn3, eqn4};

Outer[characteristicEquations[#, "form" -> #2, 
   "dummyVariable" -> t] &, eqs, {"abstract", "standard", "Charpit"}]



Char-Pit, yumm. :)  +1

What you call "characteristic equations" are not the characteristic equations but the characteristic ODEs which solving leads to the characteristic equations. The characteristic equations are not explicitly writen in your question.
Morover some of your characteristic ODEs are incomplete or false.
Before any attempt with Mathematica code it is important to clarify the analytical calculus.
First PDE:
$x\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+y\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}+xy\frac{\partial u}{\partial z}=0 \tag 1$
Charpit-Lagrange characteristic ODEs :
$\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{dy}{y}=\frac{dz}{xy}=\frac{du}{0}$
A first characteristic equation comes from necessarily $du=0$ thus :
$u=c_1$
A second characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{dy}{y}$ leading to :
$\frac{y}{x}=c_2$
A third characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{dz}{xy}=\frac{dz}{xc_2x}$
$dz=c_2xdx \quad\implies\quad 2z=c_2x^2+c_3$
$2z-xy=c_3$
The general solution of the PDE $(1)$ on implicit form $c_1=F(c_2\:,\:c_3)$ gives :
$$u(x,y,z)=F\left(\frac{y}{x}\:,\:(2z-xy)\right)$$
$F$ is an arbitrary function of two variables.
If some boundary conditions are specified one expect to determine the function $F$.
Second PDE :
$y\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}-x\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=x-y \tag 2$
Charpit-Lagrange characteristic ODEs :
$\frac{dx}{y}=\frac{dy}{-x}=\frac{dz}{0}=\frac{du}{x-y}$
Note : it is not $=\frac{dz}{x-y}$
A first characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dx}{y}=\frac{dy}{-x}$ leading to :
$x^2+y^2=c_1$
A second characteristic equation comes from necessarily $dz=0$ thus $z=c_2$.
A third characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dx}{y}=\frac{du}{x-y}$
$du=\frac{x-y}{y}dx=\left(\frac{x}{y}-1\right)dx=\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{c_1-x^2}}-1\right)dx$
$u=\int\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{c_1-x^2}}-1\right)dx = -\sqrt{c_1-x^2} -x+c_3=-y-x+c_3$
The general solution of the PDE $(2)$ on implicit form $c_3=F(c1\:,\:c_2)$ leads to :
$$u(x,y,z)=-x-y+F\left( (x^2+y^2)\:,\: z \right)$$
$F$ is an arbitrary function of two variables.
If some boundary conditions are specified one expect to determine the function $F$
Note : Since the variable $z$ doesn't appear in the PDE $(2)$ one can consider that $z$ doesn't exists in the solution as signifiant variable. With this way of seeing the solution is
$$u(x,y)=-x-y+F\left(x^2+y^2 \right)$$
Third PDE :
$y\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}+z\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=\frac{y}{x} \tag 3$
There is no $u(x,y,z)$ in the PDE but partial derivatives of $z$. So one doesn't look for $u(x,y,z)$ but one looks for $z(x,y)$.
Charpit-Lagrange characteristic ODEs :
$\frac{dx}{y}=\frac{dy}{z}=x\frac{dz}{y}$
A first characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dx}{y}=x\frac{dz}{y}\quad\implies\quad \frac{dx}{x}=dz$ leading to :
$z-\ln|x|=c_1$
A second characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dx}{y}=\frac{dy}{z}=\frac{dy}{c_1+\ln|x|}$
$ydy=(c_1+\ln|x|)dx\quad\implies\quad \int ydy=\int (c_1+\ln|x|)dx \quad\implies\quad \frac12 y^2=x\ln|x|-x+c_1x+c_2 = \frac12 y^2=x\ln|x|-x+(z-\ln|x|)x+c_2$
$\frac12 y^2+x-xz=c_2$
The general solution of the PDE $(3)$ on implicit form $c_1=F(c_2)$ leads to :
$$z=\ln|x|+F\left(\frac12 y^2+x-x\,z \right)$$
$F$ is an arbitrary function.
In this case the general solution is obtained on the form of implicit eqution (Because $z$ appears inside the arbitrary function).
An explicit equation for $z(x,y)$ cannot be derived without particular cases of boundary condition.
Forth PDE :
$x\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=x+y+2z \tag 4$
There is no $u(x,y,z)$ in the PDE but partial derivatives of $z$. So one doesn't look for $u(x,y,z)$ but one looks for $z(x,y)$.
Charpit-Lagrange characteristic ODEs :
$\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{dy}{0}=\frac{dz}{x+y+2z}$
A first characteristic equation comes from necessarily $dy=0$ thus $y=c_1$
A second characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{dz}{x+c_1+2z}$
$\frac{dz}{dx}=\frac{x+c_1+2z}{x}$ wich is a first order linear ODE leading to :
$z=c_2x^2-x-\frac{c_1}{2}$
The general solution of the PDE $(4)$ on the form of implicit equation $c_2=F(c_1)$ leads to $z=x^2F(y)-x-\frac{y}{2}$
$$z(x,y)=-x-\frac{y}{2}+x^2F(y)$$
$F$ is an arbitrary function to be determinedif some boundary condition is specified.
Note : There is no derivative wrt $y$ into the PDE $(4)$ only a partial derivative wrt $x$. Thus the PDE can be seen as a simple ODE where $y$ isn't a significant variable but a parameter. In this case the above result could be obtained directly in treating the equation $(4)$ as an ODE.

Well, I think the terminology isn't too big a problem here. The term characteristic equations is indeed used for ODE in the link provided by OP.

@xzczd. OK. I agree. But a not quite right terminology induces ambiguities. This may lead to incomplete or even false analytic equation of the general solution of the PDE.
